# How to fscanf from a .csv which is a output of fprintf

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I want to fscanf a csv file which is a output of fprintf, I set the same format but it didn't work, which means when I use that function to fscanf the file I just made, it didn't succuss, even didn't get into the while-loop. So, how to modify it to make it work?

### Below part of my code

**part of fprintf**

```
fp = fopen("Out.csv", "w");
fprintf(fp, "%99s,%d,%99s,%99s\n", current->group, current->id, current->name, 
                    current->address);
```

**part of fscanf**

```
fp = fopen("Out.csv", "r");
while (fscanf(fp, "%99s,%d,%99s,%99s\n", group, &id, name, address) == 4) {
        head = push_sort(head, group, name, id, address);
        printf("%99s", name);
}
```

Comment: One difference is that `%s` in `*scanf` reads strings up to the next space character, whereas `%s` strings in `*printf` may have scaces. Do you have spaces in your strings?

Comment: Or, better yet, `fgets` - reads entire lines with no problems.

Comment: Both of  them didn't work, but @user3121023,this one, did get the id, but others didn't show up, the result is like : group :"Nothing"  id : 1   name:"Nothing" address :"Nothing",(Nothing means really nothing showed up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's because `"%s"` specifier in `*scanf()` family stops scanning when it finds a white space, you can tell `fscanf()` which specific character to ignore, and it will stop at that character.

I believe the following format string will work

```
"%99[^,],%d,%99[^,],%99[^,\n]\n"
```

read [this link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) to find out why I think the pattern will work, search specifically for the `[` specifier.

The `*scanf()` functions are hard, it's always difficult to make them work correctly, although if you are generating the line and you're sure of what it contains and no surprises will happen, you can trust it to work.

You will be safe if you check the return value, which you do, so if you fail to read lines that you consider valid, then you can try to `fgets()` a line from the file, and parse it with `strchr()` or `strtok()`, I prefer `strchr()` because

1. It doesn't need to alter the input string.
2. It's thread safe and reentrant.
3. It allows you to infere more, like the length of the token, without `strlen()`.

Comment: This one worked, but I don't quite understand the [^,] thing you write, is this regular expression？

Comment: No, it's not regular expression, it just means match everything except all characters between the brackets. The reason why it's **excluding** the characters between the brackets is the caret `^`, if you write `%[A-Za-z0-9 ]` it might also work, because it means that it will match all the characters between the brackets, note that there is no `^` in this case, and `A-Z` is a character range, of which you can have several like `a-zA-Z` which means all the characters from the english alphabeth.